# Navigate from HomeScreen to other screen react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, navigation

I'm very new in RN and i was making simple app and got this error:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"LoginScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'LoginScreen'?
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

My App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import  LoginScreen  from './screens/LoginScreen'
import  HomeScreen  from './screens/HomeScreen'


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import { StackActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AuditScreen from './AuditScreen';
import ReportAuditScreen from './ReportAuditScreen';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';



const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      navigation.replace("Login")
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }

  

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Text>Siema Home</Text>
        <Button title="Out" onPress={handleSignOut}/>
        <Button title="Audit" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AuditScreen")}/>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

I want to go to AuditScreen after click Audit button.

Comment: Verify in your codebase that you are not calling `navigate` with `"LoginScreen"`, as you only have a `"Login"` named route.

Comment: Changed it for AuditScreen but same error

Comment: You have only two screens in your `Stack.Navigator` which are `"Login"` and `"Home"`. If you want others, you should add them first.